# Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly

Tags: javascript, python, tcl

I got this error whilst trying to run my Python code:

```
PS C:\Codes>  & 'C:\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '50412' '--' 'C:\Codes\Python Scripts\py snake.py' 
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Codes\Python Scripts\py snake.py", line 131, in <module>
    window = Tk()
             ^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2326, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/lib/tcl8.6 C:/lib/tcl8.6 C:/lib/tcl8.6 C:/library C:/library C:/tcl8.6.12/library C:/tcl8.6.12/library


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I checked my file manager, and I'm seeing `tcl.init` in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3`
I also installed tcl again thinking that it might be a problem with the version (tcl.8.6.11) and it's in my downloads folder. Do I need to move it to another folder? What is the right folder?
I'm expecting to be able to run and debug my Python codes.

EDIT: JS code has the same issue too. Probably all of the programming languages related to Tcl?

Comment: And notice how `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\tcl\tix8.4.3` is not `C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/lib/tcl8.6`, which is where _Python_ is looking for TCL. The error is showing you all the folder it checked, and none of them are the folder you say you happened to find a `tcl.init` in. It needs to be the right version of TCL in the right location.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter needs to have (or find) a full Tcl+Tk installation somewhere, not just the C library part; there are *critical* pieces implemented in scripts. When the script pieces aren't there, things break exactly as shown. If you were using a Python build without the bits written in Python, it would also break nastily! Tcl (and Tk) up through 8.6 versions is quite particular about this (unless you do some packaging steps that have never been part of how Python handles this integration).

Note that the missing `init.tcl` is just a canary in the coal-mine (and the first one searched for); the other essential scripted parts are probably also missing.

The options at this point depend on whether you've got an installation and just aren't finding it, or simply haven't got an installation at all. Either way, you end up having to either persuade the code to use the installation you've got or to provide an installation it can use. **Persuading the code to use the installation** is something you'd do by setting the `TCL_LIBRARY` and `TK_LIBRARY` environment variables, but be aware that the matching must be exact; those environment variables are *usually not recommended* (outside of internal testing) because of the version binding problems, as an installation typically knows exactly where its scripts should be anyway (the error message tells you exactly where it looked; `C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/lib/tcl8.6` in your case). **Providing an installation** is exactly what it says; I don't know the details of how to configure your Python installation to use a Tcl and Tk installation you've done in an alternate location.

---

The `init.tcl` from Tix is probably not the right one. That's (part of) a package for Tcl/Tk, not the main initialisation code for Tcl. (The package provides some extra widget components that are mainly used by old code.)